# Grails: How to get dates in g:textField from calendar?

Tags: grails, calendar, datepicker, textfield, date-format

I have four entry fields from a search filter.
I was originally using `g:datePicker` but it was not quite what I wanted, it was too slow to select the date from drop down boxes, so I decided it was better to use a simple grails text field and next to it a calendar image that would trigger the calendar.
I was trying to use the YUI Calendar, from the YUI Plugin, but I couldn't make it work correctly when formatting the date.

Any ideas on how to do this??

Like if you think about it is just the calendar image next to the text field that triggers the calendar and puts the clicked date in the desired format in the text field, but for some reason is more complicated than that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We originally used the Grail-UI plugin for datepickers and such, but found some actions to be more difficult than we had hoped.  We then found jQuery-UI and have since made the move for all our UI widgets.  I would highly recommend the jQuery-UI datepicker as a better route than text fields or dropdowns.

Comment: I like jquery better as well, and am glad they're switching to from prototype to jquery in 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand what your problem was with the YUI Plugin and date formatting. If you expand on that we might be able to help.

I would, however, recommend using the [GrailsUI](http://grails.org/plugin/grails-ui) plugin which depends on the YUI plugin.

### Install

```
grails install-plugin grails-ui
```

### View

In your view make sure you include the appropriate components in your `head` section e.g.:

```
<head>
  ...
  <gui:resources components="datePicker"/>
  ...
</head>
```

Also change the `<body>` tag to `<body class="yui-skin-sam">` if you want the default styles (skin) to apply.

Then you should be able to use:

```
<gui:datePicker id="myDateValue" value="${new Date()}" />
```

or if you want to set the format of the date:

```
<gui:datePicker id="myDateValue" formatString="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" value="${new Date()}" />
```

### Controller

When using the value from a `datePicker` in the controller, it should be treated as a string i.e.

```
Date.parse("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", params.myDateValue)
```

Comment: The thing is that I need the date in format ddMMMyy (13JUL10) and I tried doing it with Grails UI but they don't have that format :/ then I did some research in Google and YUI 2 has it. But I'm not sure how to implement YUI 2 with Grails :/ or a jscalendar that is triggered whenever a click an image next to the `g:textField` and puts the clicked date in the `g:textField` would do the job too, but I don't know how to do it